# changing css using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Im trying to do a link from one page to another, on the link itself I send a variable that the receiving page gets with php, then I need the php to echo out js to change the css display on two divs, changing the div whose default css is block to that of hidden and a second div whose default css is none to that of block. I have suucesfully passed the variable within the url, and the js to change the second div to block works, however the 1st div css doesnt seem to change to none as the div still shows

PHP code

```
if (isset($_GET['display'])) {

    if(!isset($_GET['yes'])) {

        echo '<style type="text/css">

              #slideshow {
                  display: none;
              }
              </style>';

        echo '<style type="text/css">

              #aboutus {
                  display: block;
              }
              </style>';
    }

}else{



};
```

Can anyone help me resolve this please

Comment: Seems like a horrible idea, just use a class on the element or something like that instead ?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the Javascript, not the PHP. Show that.

Comment: You can remove else PHP part since it is empty --- else{ };
The above code is inside header? If inline CSS is acceptable, you may skip the javascript part altogether and apply CSS just with PHP.

Comment: How does your url query looks like? If it's `?display=yes` , then instead of `if(!isset($_GET['yes']))` use `if(trim($_GET['display']) != 'yes')`

Comment: @adeneo, I agree.  I would change the class of the divs as I emit/echo them and put the css where it belongs in the css file.

Comment: The css is on an external style sheet, @dev101 The php is before any of the html code, would it be better putting the css in the head of the document to make this work?. @ Artur Filipiak  I have changed the php to reflect your suggestion as I accept the logic used, and it has also been mentioned in other responces to this question

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't mean this:

```
if($_GET['display'] == 'yes') {
```

I would pass an integer value rather than 'yes' and 'no'.

Then do it this way:

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=84600');
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>page Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
</head><body><div id="page">

EOT;
ob_flush();

$display = inval($_GET['display']); 

$aboutclass = array(' class="hide" ','');
$slideclass = array('',' class="hide" ');

echo '<div id="aboutus" ' . $aboutclass [$display] . '>'
echo '<div id="slideshow" ' . $slideclass [$display] . '>'


echo '</div></body></html>';
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Do I put the css styling in the header? thats where I put it, then the rest in the php, after resolving some syntax errors I saved and loaded the page and got a blank page, perhaps I havent iserted this correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using the following code

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['display']) != 'yes'){

$slider = 'block';


$aboutus = 'none';


}else{

$slider = 'none';

$aboutus = 'block';

}
```

Then I removed the display stying from the external stylesheet for the .slideShow and .aboutus and added inline styles just for the display within the head section of the html code as follows

```
<style type="text/css">

.sliderWrapper {
    display: <?php echo $slider; ?>
}

.aboutUs {
    display: <?php echo $aboutus; ?>

    };
</style>
```

Then it worked as required.

Comment: You can further simplify and optimize the above code and write it to be much faster and keep external css part for performance and clarity (your original code was on a right path), but it didn't work because of wrong second if line in PHP. As already told no need for javascript at all.

Comment: I only added the second if to try and get the code working, as I said I got the about us div to show but couldnt get the slideshow div to hide, and I agree logically it should have worked

Comment: Also I need to do this four or five times from other pages so I know my skills arent evolved enough to find a simpler way to do this.